# Separable DE Substitution

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Hi I'm trying to solve a separable DE with a worked solution.

Question:
$y′ = (y−9x)^2$

Part of the Given Solution:
Letting $v = y − 9x$
becomes $\frac{dv}{dx} = v(x)^2 − 9$

I get that $\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx} - 9$ but how does the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ become a $v(x)^2$

Thanks

Comment: What did the original DE tell you?

Comment: @Chris: **Hint:** write $y = v + 9x \implies y' = v' +9$. Now substitute those two relationships into the original DE, simplify and solve for $v(x)$, then substituent one more time for the final solution.

Comment: @Moo , thanks that was what I was looking for.. I knew it had to be something obvious I was missing!